# document.URL in href

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I don't to use the same URL in href tag plus 1 parameter. Something like:

```
<a href=document.URL+"?page=${loop.index}">${loop.index}</a>
```

But that's what I got

http://127.0.0.1:7001/tdk/device-catalogue/document.URL+%22?page=2"

I've tried as well using

```
 <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/page=${loop.index}">${loop.index}</a>
```

But then I lose part of the URL

```
tdk/device-catalogue/app-222
```

and I got only http://127.0.0.1:7001/tdk/?page=2

I've tried as well, but then it gives me the path to the JSP not of the mapping !

```
a href="${pageContext.request.requestURI}/?page=${loop.index}">${loop.index}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="?page=${loop.index}">${loop.index}</a>
```